# .NET 2.0 WebService not available in Xamarin.Forms default portable solution

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a new project in Xamarin Studio, exactly a Empty Xamarin.Forms Portable solution but when I add a WebReference the drop down menu to select the NET framework 2.0 WebServices is disabled. Because?

Comment: Why do you need 2.0? I assume that it isn't compatible with PCL.

Comment: because the WS (third-party) who I need is a .NET 2.0 style webservice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because WCF is the only WebServices framework included in .Net Framework 4 or 4.5 client.

Asp.NET would be required for Net Framework 2.0 Web Services and that would make the solution not portable to some environments, such as Windows Phone 8.